# Caching getCapabilities response with Map

Tags: javascript, caching

In my JS app, I'm trying to cache the `getCapabilities` responses for my WMTS services only.

I have this function, but when the function is called twice with the exact same `baseUrl` in the `layer` object, the request is sent twice anyway.

It does look like the `Map` object is being reinitialized in between calls though. I tried to add a global counter to the function and at every call, the counter was stuck to 0.

I'm also willing to try other caching solutions than `Map`.

Here's my code :

```
const cache = new Map()

export async function getCapabilities(layer, capabilitiesTimeout) {
  const libFetch = require('whatwg-fetch').fetch;
  const url = new URL(layer.views[0]?.baseUrl);
  const cachedRequestId = layer.views[0]?.baseUrl;

  if (!cache.get(cachedRequestId)) {
    const version = layer.views[0].serviceVersion;
    url.searchParams.append('SERVICE', layer.views[0].serviceType);
    url.searchParams.append('REQUEST', 'GetCapabilities');
    url.searchParams.append('VERSION', version);
  
    let response;
    let parsedResponse;
  
    try {
      response = await timeout(capabilitiesTimeout, fetch(getProxiedUrl(url)));
      const text = await response.text();
  
      if (layer.views[0].serviceType === TYPE_WMTS) {
        parsedResponse = parser.read(text);
        cache.set(cachedRequestId, parsedResponse);
      } else if (layer.views[0].serviceType === TYPE_WMS) {
        parsedResponse = parserWms.read(text);
      }
  
      return parsedResponse;
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn(
        `'GetCapabilities' timeout (${capabilitiesTimeout}ms) for layer "${
          layer?.title
        }"`,
        e
      );
    }
  }
  return cache.get(cachedRequestId)
}
```

Comment: "*I tried to add a global counter to the function*" - can you show us how you did that?

Comment: Btw what does `timeout` do? You should better pass a `AbortSignal.timeout()` as the [`signal` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#signal) to `fetch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It does look like the `Map` object is being reinitialized in between calls though

No, it's not. Rather the problem is that …

> when the function is called twice with the exact same `baseUrl` in the layer object, the request is sent twice anyway

… because you are not storing anything in the `cache` until the response is received. So while the first request is still under way, the second call to `getCapabilities` will see an empty cache and make its own request.

The solution to this problem is to cache the promise itself, immediately when the first call is made.

```
export async function getCapabilities(layer, capabilitiesTimeout) {
  try {
    return await getCapabilitesCached(layer.views[0], AbortSignal.timeout(capabilitiesTimeout));
  } catch(err) {
    if (err.name == 'TimeoutError') {
      console.warn(
        `'GetCapabilities' timeout (${capabilitiesTimeout}ms) for layer "${
          layer?.title
        }"`,
        err
      );
    }
    throw err; // don't forget to rethrow!
  }
}

const cache = new Map();
function getCapabilitesCached(view, signal) {
  if (view.serviceType === TYPE_WMTS) {
    const cachedRequestId = view.baseUrl;
    if (!cache.has(cachedRequestId)) {
      cache.set(cachedRequestId, fetchCapabilities(view, signal));
      //                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      // no `await` before the `cache.set` call!
    }
    return cache.get(cachedRequestId);
  } else {
    return fetchCapabilities(view, signal);
  }
}

const { fetch } = require('whatwg-fetch');
async function fetchCapabilities(view, signal) {
  const url = new URL(view.baseUrl);
  url.searchParams.append('SERVICE', view.serviceType);
  url.searchParams.append('REQUEST', 'GetCapabilities');
  url.searchParams.append('VERSION', view.serviceVersion);
  
  const response = await fetch(getProxiedUrl(url), { signal });
  const text = await response.text();
  
  if (view.serviceType === TYPE_WMTS) {
    return parser.read(text);
  } else if (view.serviceType === TYPE_WMS) {
    return parserWms.read(text);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! I figured it had something to do with the ```async``` nature of the call, but couldn't figure out how to get around that.